# Another figure problem, trying to figure out the pattern/rule

Tags: visual

This is similar to the another one I posted but want to see what people think the answer is and why.These are practice questions from an assessment company but these seem quite interesting.
[image]

Answer (score 13):

It would be

> The second one down.

Looking at the first square in the example, let's call the top dot A and the lower one B.

> Dot A travels down to the left and then up to the right.  Think of it as an oscillating dot on that diagonal.  Dot B appears to travel like a knight in chess, so in the second square, it is at top left, then bottom middle, then top right, and the only option from the right is middle left.